# How to proxy or impersonate a user for another SVN server?

Tags: svn, version-control, reverse-proxy, impersonation

The problem:
There is one svn server on our network that doesn't have a read-only user and can't add new users or permissions for various reasons. I know this is a ridiculous problem but that's how it is.

The Goal:
I'd like to add some kind of reverse-proxy / pass-through / or impersonation layer in front of that server so I can provide a user account that is read only for build services but behind the scenes will access the main SVN repo using my personal read/write credentials.

What is a reasonable approach to achieve that goal?

Thoughts?

Comment: Better solution would be to use your credentials export the repository and create an svn server where you can add new users and set permissions and then import the entire export preserving the history. SVN Repositories are designed to be highly portable and can be easily moved.

Comment: @SiddharthKaul I thought about that but it's a monster huge repo and I'd rather not duplicate all of it.